# Почему изображение по нажатию не перемещается?

Tags: javascript

Хотел сделать при зажатии кнопки перемещение изображения, когда отпускают кнопку - движение останавливается. Но, не работает.

Почему изображение по нажатию не перемещается?

```js
var start = Date.now();
var interval;
$("button").mousedown(function() {
    interval = setInterval(performWhileMouseDown, 100);
}).mouseup(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);  
});
function performWhileMouseDown() {
    var timePassed = Date.now() - start;  
    $("#train").css('left', timePassed / 5 + 'px');
}
```

```css
#train {
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Двигать поезд</button>
<img id="train" src="https://js.cx/clipart/train.gif">
```

Comment: **У вас неправильный синтаксис**!
Если вы указываете тег `<script></script>` двумя способами одновременно (т.е. указывая код между тегами `<script></script>` и самой ссылкой `<script src="...">`), то содержимое внутри тегов игнорируется.

Comment: у меня все работает.

Comment: почему вы удалили старый вопрос, взяв оттуда ответ, и задали с ним новый?))))00

Comment: @ThisMan, а почему вы редактируете вопрос, починив ошибку в которой и был вопрос?

Comment: @СергейПетрашко действительно:D тогда вопрос не имеет смысла, потому что вызван опечаткой)

Answer (score -1):

```
<style>
    #train {
        position: absolute;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
</style>
<button>Двигать поезд</button>
<img id="train" src="https://js.cx/clipart/train.gif">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        var start = Date.now();
    var interval;
    $("button").mousedown(function() {
        interval = setInterval(performWhileMouseDown, 100);
        console.log('123')
    }).mouseup(function() {
        clearInterval(interval);  
    });
    function performWhileMouseDown() {
        var timePassed = Date.now() - start;  
        $("#train").css('left', timePassed / 5 + 'px');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: вы бы хоть написали в чем ошибка то, а то еще и в вашем коде разбираться людям